# Losing authentication on dnx restart

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using cookie authentication in an ASP.NET MVC6 application.  My configuration is as follows:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.CookieName = "ow.2a";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "r";
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "TwoFactor";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4.0);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/login");
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
});
```

And here's my login code:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("TwoFactor",  
    new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
        { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()) }, "Password")),  
    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4.0) });
```

I've noticed that every once in a while (around 15 minutes), I've noticed that I get logged off.  I've followed [these instructions](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) to host my application on IIS.  The problem seems related to the dnx process restarting.  I can understand shutting down this process after a certain period of inactivity, but do not know why the authentication cookie would then become invalid.  Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authentication cookies are encrypted. Unless you ran the provisioning script mentioned in the docs;

> To persist Data Protection keys you must create registry hives for
>   each application pool to store the keys. You should use the
>   [Provisioning PowerShell script](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/dev/Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1) for each application pool you will
>   be hosting ASP.NET 5 applications under.

or you have [configured data protection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html) manually in your code the keys will be held in memory and discarded when the app stops. So, did you follow **all** the steps in the instructions? :)

Comment: That would be it..  I didn't have any application/user specific keys so I didn't think I needed to configure data protection..

Comment: That's why that step is there :) I will submit a change to make it clearer.